# PHP bad regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Hey I'm getting a very in-descriptive REG_BADRPT error on the following line:

```
if(ereg('(?=^.{8,20}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$', $_POST['password']))
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?

I've used the same regex in javascript and it works fine so not sure what the problem is here.

What I'm trying to achieve here is set a regex that would validate strings that contain:

- At least one lower case letter
- At least one upper case letter
- At least one number or symbol
- and should be between 8 and 20 characters long

Comment: It looks like you're trying to test a password for various properties.  Have you considered breaking up the tests into logical chunks?  E.G. test that the length is 8-20 characters, then that it contains uppercase, lowercase, digits, etc. rather than putting it all in one giant hard-to-debug regex?

Comment: @Qsario Yeah I was actually trying to avoid that but I will probably have to..

Comment: While I appreciate terse code, clarity is important too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up changing the regex with this one and it works fine:

```
if(preg_match("#.*^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$#", $_POST['password']))
```

Stil dont know what the problem was before

Answer (score 4):

Ereg is deprecated in php 5.3. Try using `preg_match('/(?=^.{8,20}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/', $string)` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string your trying to match? I just executed the code below and I received no error.
`$string = 'test';

if (preg_match('/(?=^.{8,20}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/',$string)) {
   print('true');
} else {
  print('false');
}`

Comment: Ok I'm trying the fastest password in the world asdASD12..It validates in javascript but here it complains

Comment: Oh and btw test should not validate as it should require at least one upper,one lower, one number or special character and a min of 8 chars length